# How to set tab badge from app delegate

Tags: objective-c, ios, delegates, uitabbaritem, badge

I'm trying to set the tab badge number on launch when I receive a push or local notification. Accordingly, I'm trying to set this badge number from the Application Delegate. I can set the badge locally from the tab's view controller with `self.tabBarItem.badgeValue`, and I can set up a method to set it which I can call from the delegate, but there must be a better solution.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any problem with this. It's called the AppDelegate for a reason, so that it can act as the main controller for other controllers.